# Why Rails model is not writing values to database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, model, database-migration

I am new to Rails and my applications is doing everything as intended except writing the right values to de database, each model instance is created but all values passed to it are being null.

***Github link to application :*** *https://github.com/aldeano19/railsLearn*

**Model**

```
class Oneinfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name, :number

end
```

**Controller**

```
class InfoController < ApplicationController
  $names = {}
  @show = true

  def print
    if request.request_method_symbol == :get
      $names = {}
      @show = false
    else
      @show = true

      name = params[:myinfo][:name]
      number = params[:myinfo][:number]
      $names[name] = number

      @newinfo = Oneinfo.new(oneinfo_params)
      @newinfo.save
    end
  end

  private
    def oneinfo_params
      params.require(:myinfo).permit(:name, :number)
    end
end
```

**View**

```
<h1>Info print</h1>
<%= form_for :myinfo do |a| %>
  <%= a.label :name %>
  <%= a.text_field :name %><br>
  <br>
  <%= a.label :number%>
  <%= a.text_field :number%><br>
  <br>
  <%= a.submit %>
<%end%>

<div id="clear" style="display: <%= @show ? 'inline' : 'none' %> ">
  <%= form_for :button do |b|%>
    <%link_to 'clear', info_print_path %>
    <%end%>
</div>

<% $names.each do |key, val|%>
  <%=key%> &nbsp 
  <%=val%><br>
<%end%>
```

** MYSQL Database after 7 Models have being submited**

```
+----+------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name | number | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | NULL |   NULL | 2014-10-28 19:28:14 | 2014-10-28 19:28:14 |
|  2 | NULL |   NULL | 2014-10-28 23:32:31 | 2014-10-28 23:32:31 |
|  3 | NULL |   NULL | 2014-10-28 23:32:37 | 2014-10-28 23:32:37 |
|  4 | NULL |   NULL | 2014-10-28 23:33:10 | 2014-10-28 23:33:10 |
|  5 | NULL |   NULL | 2014-10-28 23:33:32 | 2014-10-28 23:33:32 |
|  6 | NULL |   NULL | 2014-10-28 23:33:34 | 2014-10-28 23:33:34 |
|  7 | NULL |   NULL | 2014-10-28 23:33:43 | 2014-10-28 23:33:43 |
+----+------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: What if you drop `attr_accessor :name, :number` from model?

Comment: Please be more explanatory. What do you mean by `drop`, does that means to delete `attr_accessor :name, :number`in the model?, to delete it from the database?. Sorry is just that I am really new to Rails.

Comment: To be more specific: delete that line from `Oneinfo` model.

Comment: If `name` and `number` are already record attributes, you don't want `attr_accessor` for them since that will create new accessors for your clase that hide the database attributes.

Comment: That solved it! I was following a tutorial but it didn't explain what that line was for, could you please briefly tell me why was this line breaking it and when should it be used, I really appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete `attr_accessor :name, :number` from Oneinfo model.

`attr_accessor` creates instance methods (reader and writer) for your class. So, for instance, instead of having:

```
class Car
  # reader
  def engine
    @engine
  end

  #writer
  def engine=(engine)
    @engine = engine
  end
end
```

you can write:

```
class Car
  attr_accessor :engine
end
```

The clue here is that `attr_accessor :name, :number` overrides the default behaviour of your model fields. In real cases, you do not need to specify `attr_accessor` for any of your model fields, unless you would need to extend your model with some extra fields, which are not defined in your database table.